# How to detect if same user signin from another android device?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

If I install whatup on a different device with same phone number, the old device's whats app does not work. Similar to that, in flutter App, I want to know if a user has signed up on new device while leaving signed on another device.

There is [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14724949/how-to-detect-another-android-device) proposed,but what about if there is no phone number or permission not granted

another [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40887882/android-how-to-detect-same-user-from-multiple-devices) is about token, but token change as [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37678248/in-what-period-does-the-firebases-app-token-changes-and-how-to-manage-it), so the best could be invalidate the session, but I could not find how to invalidate the session.

Comment: You could create a user agent by using device info package and / or google ad id. For session if token expired check what sstatus code your back end is sening and do what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but what about if there is no phone number or permission not granted

Then use something else as the unique identifier, for example my team uses [flutter_udid](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_udid) to keep track of licensing. We haven't had any issues with it so far hence why I am recommending that one, but there are others that serve the same purpose out there.

> but I could not find how to invalidate the session.

That is entirely backend related and is a "problem" of its own, you should write a new question dedicated for that. Also don't forget to tell what you are using as a backend (you haven't done so in this question).

Comment: thanks, what are the other unique identifier , just so I know the options